# Generating unique version for application if any dependency of application is changed?

Tags: unix, makefile, cmake

Currently how I am doing. 
On build start Currently I am generating version.h having current version of source code as APPLICATION_VERSION. Which is getting used in every application.

Problem with this approach is that if any file changed in source it force every application to be rebuild.

I want to generate application related version.h any only if any other dependency leaving version.txt is changed for that binary. 
Currently I am using cmake for my build process. What will be good solution for the problem ?

**Edit More Details:**

My directory structure is like this:

```
app/
   common/
         version.h
   app1/
       main.c
       other source file
   app2
       main.c
       other source file
lib/
   third party libs.
```

Every app main.c is including version.h. So only main.c will be get recompiled when version is getting changes. So compilation is not issue with me. 
Problem is that let's assume I have modified a dependency which affects only app1. Now if I am building the app. 
version.h will be get changes as source code version is changed. Due to change in version.h It will change version of both app app1 and app2. 
I want to avoid changing version of the app if no dependency of the app1 is changed.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are including "version.h" in most (if not every) cpp file. This causes a complete recompile of the world each time you change it. The usual approach to solve it is to

1. declare in your header
2. define/implement in your source

I suggest you change version.h, such that it "declares" a single function which should return the actual version. E.g., something simple like the following.

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#include <string>

static std::string getVersion( );

#endif // VERSION_H
```

Using CMake, I suggest you then "re-generate" your version.cpp on each build. Without example code in your question, I will present a possible approach:

Prepare a version.cpp.in, which should be "converted" by [CMake's configure_file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aconfigure_file) into a suitable version.cpp.

```
#include "version.h"

// After calling configure_file, CMake will have replaced the entry between @@ 
// with the corresponding CMake variables
static std::string generated_version=@Cmake_Generated_Version@;

std::string static getVersion( )
{
    return generated_version;
}
```

And in your cmakelists.txt do something like:

```
# Somehow fill a CMake variable Cmake_Generated_Version
configure_file( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/version.cpp.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY}/version.cpp )
```

Comment: I think, it's better to use just `extern std::string version;` instead of a function.

Comment: @arrowdodger: For simple situations, I completely agree. E.g. with only a single version string as in my example. But when there is more information than a single number or when various formats are needed I think a set of methods can be more extendible.

Comment: @Andre It is not going to solve my problem. I want to run configure only if any other dependency of executable is changed. Current solution will run configure on each build.

Comment: @Vivek, I had the feeling there were two parts to your question. 1) How to prevent a full rebuild after updating version.h 2) How to generate version.h nicely. I tried to answer 1), but could not completely understand your issues with 2). Perhaps you could update the question with some code demonstrating your problems?